# List all xml files with filename under a amazon S3 folder based on search pattern

Tags: java, c#, xml, amazon-s3

I have requirement to accept search field on runtime  and then search through xml files stored under particular AWS s3 bucket abd display file names on console.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand really what you want! you need to search into the xml file or only search the name of the file with a specific pattern?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! I only need to search name of file based on specific pattern

Answer (score 0):

Below code in Python (I know you asked in Java, please treat it as a reference) lists all objects in a particular bucket and then prints only the ones for which filename contains a certain text string. You can enhance this code based on your requirements:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
testString='someString'
objResp = client.list_objects(Bucket='my-specific-bucket')

for i in objResp['Contents']:
   if testString in i['Key']:
      print (i['Key'])
```

Please also note that list_objects in boto3 Python returns 1000 objects maximum, so if your buckets will have more objects, you will have to address that scenario as well by making use of 'IsTruncated' flag. Please check official documentation.

Comment: thanks for sharing this. it helped to start off. Are you aware of any reference code how to print file name based on search on file contents

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html

This is an example code provided from AWS for listing all object into a bucket using the Java SDK. 
You can find all the SDK documentation into the docs. For example it is possible to add a prefix.

Comment: Thanks for sharing . Are you aware of any reference code how to print file name based on search on file contents

Answer (score 0):

Get all objects from S3 bucket and iterate all objects to find objects with name that have a name with the pattern:

```
ObjectListing objects = amazonS3.listObjects("s3-bucket");

        objects.getObjectSummaries().forEach(object -> {
            if (object.getKey().matches("YOUR_PATTERN")) {
               // do what you want to do with object
                System.out.println(object.getKey());
            }
          }
        );
```

Comment: This may well provide the solution, but your answer would be much more useful if you provided some explanation.